# @NamedNativeQuery + @SqlResultSetMapping + @ConstructorResult + @ColumnResult results in classCastException

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I want to select specific columns from the table and store the results to the non-entity POJO.

My Entity class :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "CUSTOMER")
@NamedNativeQuery(name = "findSampleMapping", 
    query = "SELECT CUSTOMER_ID, NAME, REG_TIMESTAMP FROM CUSTOMER where CUSTOMER_ID = ?1", resultSetMapping = "SampleMapping")
@SqlResultSetMapping(name="SampleMapping",
classes = {
 @ConstructorResult(targetClass = com.entity.Sample.class,
   columns = {@ColumnResult(name="customerId"), @ColumnResult(name="name"), @ColumnResult(name="regTimeStamp")}
 )}
)
public class CustomerEntity {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "CUSTOMER_ID")
    private String customerId;

    @Column(name = "NAME")
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "FIRST_NAME")
    private String firstName;

   @Column(name = "LAST_NAME")
    private String lastName;

   @Column(name = "REG_TIMESTAMP ")
    private String regTimeStamp;
}
```

Non-entity POJO:

```
import java.sql.Timestamp;

    public class Sample {

        private String customerId;
        private String name;
        private TimeStamp regTimeStamp;

        public Sample(String customerId, String name, TimeStamp regTimeStamp){
            this.customerId = customerId;
            this.name = name;
            this.regTimeStamp= regTimeStamp;
        }

        public String getCustomerId() {
            return customerId;
        }
        public void setCustomerId(String customerId) {
            this.customerId = customerId;
        }
        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }
        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }
        public String getRegTimeStamp() {
            return regTimeStamp;
        }
        public void setRegTimeStamp(String regTimeStamp) {
            this.regTimeStamp= regTimeStamp;
        }

    }
```

Call :

```
Query q = em.createNamedQuery("findSampleMapping");
q.setParameter(1, "1");
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
List<Sample> list = q.getResultList();

   for (Sample row : list) {
    System.out.println(row.getCustomerId());
   }
```

When I try to loop and get the values, I get classCastException in for loop Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to com.entity.Sample

Comment: i get this too.  did you find a solution?

Comment: No, I couldnt solve the issue.

Comment: in the end i removed the @SqlResultSetMapping and used `TypedQuery<Sample> q = em.createNamedQuery("findSampleMapping", Sample.class);` and it worked.  I am using OpenJPA 2.4.2.  but first i had to check what types Object[] was returning to make sure they matched the fields in Sample.  basically it is broken.  hopefully it gets fixed in JPA 2.1

Answer (score 0):

```
List<Sample> list = q.setResultTransformer(Transformers.aliasToBean(Sample.class)).getResultList();
```

Comment: @AlagammalP is your Query variable of type org.hibernate.Query? That is what I use in this circumstance.

Comment: Query is of type  javax.persistence.Query